# Is there any difference between 802.1Qbh NIV and 802.1 BR?

Tags: vlan, ethernet, protocol-theory, fex

I believe NIV is 802.1qbh and 802.1BR seems to be just an advanced version of it. By simple looks, there doesnt seem to be much difference. Can someone please confirm this? And if there are any advancements, could you please list them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe NIV is 802.1qbh and 802.1BR seems to be just an advanced version of it. By simple looks, there doesnt seem to be much difference. Can someone please confirm this?

IEEE 802.1Qbh was [withdrawn in 2011](http://standards.ieee.org/about/sasb/nescom/0911recs.pdf) in favor of IEEE 802.1BR:

[image: 802.1Qbh withdrawn]

As such, 802.1BR is simply an evolution of the abandoned Qbh standard.

According to [Rene Raeber](https://twitter.com/reneraeber) who participated in the 802.1Qbh standardization effort, there is no difference between 802.1Qbh and 802.1BR.

[image: Rene Raeber quote]

Comment: PS: I do not have enough credits to upvote. So i am sorry that i am not able to upvote.